# Matlab running max by group

Tags: matlab, max, groupwise-maximum

In Matlab, how do I compute the running maximum of an array for each group (labeled by another array `subs`)? For example, think of the array `subs` as labels for 3 students, and the corresponding values in `val` as test scores, I want to compute the the running maximum score achieved by each student.

```
>> subs = [1; 3; 1; 1; 3; 2];
>> val = [101 102 103 98 105 106];
```

The desired output has the same size as `val` and gives the current maximum score achieved by that student:

```
output = [101, 102, 103, 103, 105, 106]
```

My dataset is pretty large, with millions of entries so I would like to avoid using a for-loop. If I just wanted overall the maximum score for each student, I would use `accumarray(subs,val,[],@max)` but here the problem is more difficult since I want to running-maximum.

There is a similar question in R, but I would like to be able to do this in Matlab.
[Finding running maximum by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069496/finding-running-maximum-by-group-in-r)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a recent Matlab version you can use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with [`cummax`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html) as follows. Note that `subs` [needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775147/2586922) to be sorted first (and of course the same sorting needs to be applied to `vals` and undone at the end).

```
[subsSorted, ind] = sort(subs); %// make sure grouping variable is sorted, so that
    %// accumarray is stable
result = accumarray(subsSorted, val(ind), [], @(x) {cummax(x).'}); %'// running max of
    %// each group is computed with cummax function
result = [result{:}]; %// concatenate
result(ind) = result; %// undo sorting
```