# R: How do I calculate the maximum value seen so far in a variable for each ID

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in `R` called `df` :

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3)
day<-c(1,2,4,5,2,2,3,6,8)
payment<-c(5,10,3,30,23,40,20,10,50)
df<-data.frame(id,day,payment)

 id  day  payment
  1   1       5
  1   2      10
  1   4       3
  1   5      30
  2   2      23
  3   2      40
  3   3      20
  3   6      10
  3   8      50
```

what I'm trying to do is creating a new variable called `soFarMax`, it represents the maximum payment that the associated `id` has made until that day:

```
  id  day   payment SoFarMax
  1   1       5       5
  1   2      10       10
  1   4       3       10
  1   5      30       30
  2   2      23       23
  3   2      40       40
  3   3      20       40
  3   6      10       40
  3   8      50       50
```

Would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: See `?cummax`..

Comment: Thanks @Frank wasn't aware of it!

Comment: With base R if you are interested `ave(df$payment, df$id, FUN = cummax)`

Comment: @RonakShah Could you elaborate? There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069496/finding-running-maximum-by-group-in-r though akrun duped it against the current one.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Ronak . Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34069496/ I edited the target, will undupe, someone else can pick a more appropriate dupe, maybe from my links here.

Answer (score 2):

```
SoFarMax <- unlist(tapply(df[,3], df[,1], cummax))
```

if your order the days before it is not necessary that there already in your dataframe in order:

```
df_order <- df[order(df[,2]),]
SoFarMax <- unlist(tapply(df_order[,3], df_order[,1], cummax))
```

Answer (score 0):

The key apparently was `cummax` thanks to @Frank. Here is what I managed to come up with:

```
library(data.table)
df<-data.table(df)
df<-df[,MaxSoFar:=cummax(payment),by=list(id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(SoFarMax = cummax(payment))
```

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use window functions to group by this with IDs ( Use **dplyr or subset** for that )
and then use `cummax(x)` or you can use logic

```
df$sofarmax<-ifelse(df$payment[i]>df$payment[i-1],df$payment[i],df$payment[i-1])
```