# Add max value to a new column in R

Tags: r

This is the data:

```
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3)  
b <- c(1,3,5,9,4)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df1

a b
1 1
1 3
2 5
2 9
3 4
```

I want something like this:

```
a b max
1 1 3
1 3 3
2 5 9
2 9 9
3 4 4
```

My question: How do I compute the "max" column grouping by "a" column with value in "b" column?

I did some research with aggregate function but I still can not find the solution.

Please help

Comment: For your results, line 3, I think you meant the max should be 5 not 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use one of the group by functions which does allow to create a column instead of just `summarise` the output.  The `data.table` option is succint as the assignment (`:=`) will create a new column.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'a', get the maximum value of 'b' (`max(b)`) and assign (`:=`) as a new column.  If we need a summary, wrap it with `list` instead of `:=`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Max:= max(b), a]
```

---

or use `ave` from `base R`.   This is one of the rare base functions which will give the output as the same length of the number of rows of the original dataset.  As the first argument, we use the variable to get the `max` of, 2nd, 3rd, etc (if any) will be the grouping column.  Specify the `FUN`.  By default, if we don't specify any `FUN`, it will take the `mean` by group.

```
df1$Max <- with(df1, ave(b, a, FUN=max)
```

---

or with `dplyr`.  The `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions are flexible in ways to get either the `summary` or get a new column on the original dataset.  With `dplyr`, after we group by 'a', use `mutate` to create a new column.  If, instead, we need a summarised version, the `summarise` function can replace the `mutate` (which will give similar output as `aggregate`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   mutate(Max = max(b))
#      a     b   Max
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     1     1     3
#2     1     3     3
#3     2     5     9
#4     2     9     9
#5     3     4     4
```